# How to work with a collection of STLs

Tags: memory-management, vector, stl, stack

I am working on a vector of stacks. I have the following variable.

```
std::vector< std::stack< unsigned long > > myVectorOfStacks;
```

I am intersted in getting the stack at a certain index in the vector using the below call. 
    std::stack< unsigned long > & tempStack = myVectorOfStacks.at( stackNumber );

This is crashing. Can someone please suggest me a way out of this.

My core need is to have a stack ONLY if there isnt one. So, at the beginning, I may not have stack at index 2. For the first usage, say PUSH STACK2 VALUEA, I need to create a new stack at the 2nd location in vector. Further down the line, if I get another PUSH STACK2 VALUEB, I need to REUSE the earlier created stack and not create a new one.

Please share your thoughts.

thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `vector` `at` method you have to be sure that there is a stack with this index. That's probably what makes your code fail. There is no stack with the index you call `at` with.

When you want to add a new value to a non-existing stack you need to first create the stack. You need to make sure there is at least `stackNumber+1` stacks in your vector.

You should do somehting like this:

```
while (myVectorOfStacks.size() <= stackNumber)
  myVectorOfStacks.push_back(std::stack<unsigned long>());
std::stack<unsigned long> & tempStack = myVectorOfStacks.at(stackNumber);
tempStack.push_back(VALUEA);
```